# Is a circle of circles necessarily a 2-manifold?

Tags: gn.general-topology, smooth-manifolds, continuum-theory, torus

Let $X$ be a continuum (a compact connected metric space).

Suppose that there is a collection of simple closed curves $\mathcal C$ which partitions $X$ into pairwise-disjoint, nowhere dense sets. Suppose moreover that the decomposition $\mathcal C$ is continuous, which means that the quotient mapping $X\to \mathcal C$ is both closed and open. And suppose that the space $\mathcal C$ (in the quotient topology) is a simple closed curve.

So $X$ is a continuous "circle of circles". **Is $X$ a $2$-torus?**

Ryan Bundey pointed out in the comments that $X$ could be a Klein bottle. So let me ask for something weaker:

**Is the dimension of X at least 2?**

**Is X a 2-dimensional manifold?**

**Is every continuous "arc of circles" a cylinder?**

---

It seems like this should obviously be true. However, there are continua such as the "circle of pseudo-arcs" which make things less obvious. This is a homogeneous $1$-dimensional continuum which admits a continuous decomposition into pseudo-arcs, such that the quotient space is a simple closed curve.

Comment: I think $X$ can be a Klein bottle.

Comment: @RyanBudney True. Will revise to ask: Is the dimension of X space at least 2? Is X a 2-dimensional manifold?

Comment: What do you get if you take $(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}) \times [0,1]$ and quotient out by the equivalence relation generated by identifying $(u,1)$ with $(2u,0)$ (of course, this will also identify $(u,1)$ with $(u+\frac{1}{2},1)$)? It looks like the resulting $X$ has a partition into circles with the base being a circle, but I didn't give this much thought.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: In algebraic topology texts this would be called the mapping torus of $S^1 \ni z \longmapsto z^2 \in S^1$.

Comment: In fact, the mapping torus of any continuous map $f:S^\to S^1$ is an example, and presumably it is only when $f$ is a homeomorphism that $X$ becomes a manifold.

Comment: In grad school I was sometimes called Ryan Bundles.

Comment: I think Bundey is an English/Norman name.  Budney is Ukrainian / Polish / Belarussian, but in my case, Ukrainian.

Comment: @RyanBudney: Japanese faculty might have found that confusing: the R=L elision.

Comment: Because of the example of Tom Goodwillie, only the question on dimension 2 remains open?

Comment: @TarasBanakh Yes that seems to be the case. The main thing I would like to know is that the dimension is at least $2$.